# Match partially in the list

Tags: python

```
list1 = ['  I am Sam', 'It is 1,2,3  ', ' It is hot right now' ]

match1 = 'I am'
match2 = 'is 1,2'
match3 = 'hot right now'
```

Return true if all of match1, match2, match3 are present and match in list1. There are white strings in list1

```
def check(the_list, *match):
    return all(a in the_list for a in match)
if check(list1, match1, match2, match3):
    return True
```

I can return if it's exact match, but what's best way to match in the list even though match is partial?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'partial match'? Can you provide an example?

Comment: What is your expected output? I understand is True, but on which conditions? Is not clear from your check function.

Comment: So you want to know if each `matchX` string is a substring of at least one element in the list?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure this is what you want to do, but I reckon it is:

```
list1 = ['  I am Sam', 'It is 1,2,3  ', ' It is hot right now' ]

match1 = 'I am'
match2 = 'is 1,2'
match3 = 'hot right now'


def check(the_list, *match):
    return all(any(w in p for p in the_list) for w in match)))

print(check(list1, match1, match2, match3))
```

You want partial matches, so strings do not need to be equal, but match must be a substring of your list.

Comment: Seems to be that even if match1 is not in list1, it's returning true. If I change match1 to arbitrary string like 'not here' it's still returning True. All 3 matches have to be in list1.

Comment: You are right, I think I fixed it with a further edit.

Answer (score 1):

`a in a_string` returns `True` if `a` is a substring of `a_string`. So you just need to fix the list comprehension, which needs to be a bit more complex.

```
list1 = ['  I am Sam', 'It is 1,2,3  ', ' It is hot right now' ]

match1 = 'I am'
match2 = 'is 1,2'
match3 = 'hot right now'

def check(the_list, *match):
    return all(any(a in listel for listel in the_list) for a in match)

print(check(list1, match1, match2, match3))
```

It prints `True` if all matches are substring of at least one of the strings in `the_list`. Order does not matter and it does not require a one to one correspondence. I mean that if all the `match`es are substring of the same element, it still returns `True`. For example, if you use `match1 = 'I am'`, `match2 = 'am'`, `match3 = ' I'` it still returns `True`.

Comment: Does this work with white spaces in the list as it's just looking for substring?

Comment: `'ab'` is substring of `'  ab  '`. Does not care if other character are spaces, letters, numbers, or whatever. But `'ab'` is not substring of `'  a b  '` of course.